# Getting value of Mapping table IDs when value is from same column

Tags: mysql, join, mapping

Im really struggling to get my head around what should be simple,

I have two tables, one contains records the other is a mapping table.

records

```
ID  Title      Description
1   record 1   desc 1
2   record 2   desc 2
3   record 3   desc 3
4   record 4   desc 4
```

mapping table

```
ID1    ID2
 1      3
 2      4
```

What I want to do is get the two titles of each row in the mapping table. So the above would output

```
record 1  record 3
record 2  record 4
```

Im missing something really obvious, trying multiple joins results in errors trying to link the same table twice.

The following returns NUll

```
SELECT records.title FROM mapping
    LEFT JOIN records 
    ON mapping.ID1 = records.id
     AND mapping.ID2 = records.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one: (**UNTESTED**)

```
SELECT  b.Title as TitleA,
        c.Title as TitleB
FROM    mapping a
            INNER JOIN records b
                on a.ID1 = b.ID
            INNER JOIN records c
                on a.ID2 = c.ID
```